# Getting started with Grunt and sass (partials)

Tags: sass, gruntjs, partials

I am just getting started with Grunt and am a bit confused about how to configure my gruntfile.js to recognize changes to sass partial files. I've followed the article on [24ways.org](http://24ways.org/2013/grunt-is-not-weird-and-hard/) by Chris Coyier and feel pretty comfortable with the basics. When running grunt watch, I can make changes to my style.scss file and grunt will watch and compile changes. However, I typically use style.scss as a long list of @imports:

`@import 'partials/partialfilename';`

When I make a change to any of my partials grunt does not notice anything has changed and thus nothing is compiled.

Within my project directory I have a sass directory that includes a style.scss file and a partials directory with lots of partials.

here is my grunt file:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// 1. All configuration goes here 
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: {   
        dist: {
            src: [
                'js/custom.js', 
                'js/foundation.js',
                'js/jquery.listnav.js',
                'js/jquery.ioslider.min.js'
            ],
            dest: 'js/build-scripts.js',
        }
    },

    uglify: {
        build: {
            src: 'js/build-scripts.js',
            dest: 'js/build-scripts-min.js'
        }
    },

    imagemin: {
        dynamic: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'images/',
                src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                dest: 'images/'
            }]
        }
    },

    sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed'
            },
            files: {
                'style.css': 'sass/style.scss'
            }
        } 
    }, 

    watch: {
        options: {
            livereload: true,
        },
        scripts: {
            files: ['js/*.js'],
            tasks: ['concat', 'uglify'],
            options: {
                spawn: false,
            }
        },
        css: {
            files: ['sass/**/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['sass'],
            options: {
                spawn: false,
            }
        },

        images: {
            files: ['images/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}', 'images/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
            tasks: ['imagemin'],
            options: {
              spawn: false,
            }
        }

    }



});

// 3. Where we tell Grunt we plan to use this plug-in.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

// 4. Where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.
grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch', 'concat', 'uglify', 'imagemin', 'sass']);
```

};

I have tried a few different options for the watch css arguments such as:

```
css: {
  files: ['sass/**/*.scss'],
  tasks: ['sass'],
  options: {
    spawn: false
  }
}
```

and

```
css: {
  files: ['sass/*.scss'],
  tasks: ['sass'],
  options: {
    spawn: false
  }
}
```

I realize that I may be 'missing the point' here, I have read a bit about the grunt sass plugin 'ignoring' (_) underscores or partials because of the sass globbing rule (?) and through my research I have noticed that most people are using compass in their projects which I am not.

So, again my question is: How can I configure grunt to watch and compile changes to my sass partials and compile my css correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution.

```
css: {
  files: ['sass/*.scss'],
  files: ['sass/partials/*.scss'],
  tasks: ['sass'],
  options: {
    spawn: false,
  }
}
```

Comment: This really helped me, so thank you! I have multiple subdirectories for mixins and partials, so i used `[scss/**/*.scss'] and this enables me to save imports and compile the scss file that imports said files! few!